# What is the best filter where to use register_block_type?

Tags: hooks, actions, block-editor, init

I'm using `register_block_type` to register my blocks.

I'm not sure what is the best hook to use, between `init` and `enqueue_block_editor_assets`.

I suppose that enqueue_block_editor_assets it is loaded after, because I can use `get_the_ID`

What are the pro and cons of both?

Answer (score 1):

In the [developer docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/block-code/) they've always used the `init` hook and it's always worked for me.

Extracted from that source:

```
function create_block_gutenpride_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_gutenpride_block_init' );
```